# Making a global directive in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to create a directive to handle interaction with the navigation on my site. The directive has an `element.click` listener in the link function, which toggles the subnav that should be displayed.

Here's the html:

```
<nav class="side">
    <ul class="lower">
        <li><a subnav="settings"><i class="icon icon-fw icon-gear"></i><span>Settings</span></a></li>
        <li><a subnav="account"><i class="icon icon-fw icon-briefcase"></i><span>Account</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<nav class="subnav" ng-class="{'active': flags.subnav}">
    <ul class="sub" ng-if="flags.subnav == 'settings'">
        <!-- Settings menu options -->
    </ul>
    <ul class="sub" ng-if="flags.subnav == 'account'">
        <!-- Account menu options -->
    </ul>
</nav>
```

The initial module, which requires another module (where my directive resides):

```
var app = angular.module('App', ['navigation']).run(function($rootScope) {
    // Set a base flags object
    $rootScope.flags = {
        subnav: false
    };
});
```

And the directive itself:

```
angular.module('navigation', []).directive('subnav', function($rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.on('click', function() {
                $rootScope.flags.subnav = ($rootScope.flags.subnav == attrs.subnav) ? false : attrs.subnav;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

My issue is that the DOM is not updated. Despite the rootScope being updated if I console.log it after its changed.

I'm new to Angular, and fully aware there must be a better/more correct way of solving this. I await enlightenment with gratitude :)

Answer (score 0):

Call $apply to trigger a digest outside of the angular context

```
angular.module('navigation', []).directive('subnav', function($rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.on('click', function() {
                $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                    $rootScope.flags.subnav = ($rootScope.flags.subnav == attrs.subnav) ? false : attrs.subnav;
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried this, and made a plunker to demonstrate it still not working (see console for changing value): http://plnkr.co/edit/S69hukOFDh0EI6r23ZBR?p=preview